# C++ HTML generation classes

Tags: c++, html

A question prompted by [jbar's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779573/what-works-for-web-dev-in-c/779585#779585).

In scripting languages like Python, Ruby, and Perl, there are libraries that simplify generating dynamic HTML.  (For example, the [cgi](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html) module in Ruby.)

Are there any similar packages for C++?  I don't know of one, and at least some desultory googling didn't reveal one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt#/

I don't know anything about it, but their web-page is clean and the introduction sounds like exactly what you're looking for...

> Wt (pronounced 'witty') is a C++ library and application server for developing and deploying web applications. It is not a 'framework', which enforces a way of programming, but a library.

...

> In contrast, a web application developed with Wt is written in only one compiled language (C++), from which the library generates the necessary HTML/XHTML, Javascript, CGI, SVG/VML/Canvas and AJAX code.

Answer (score 2):

[Cgicc](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/) does HTML generation. I've toyed with it once, and it seemed pretty nice.